# How do I Make a IsEnabled type converter in XAML for an ApplicationBarMenuItem in Widows phone 8 app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Normally I would use this kind of property in a view model to control the visibility of a button (or a control) in a xaml page (using c#).

```
private Visibility downloadVideoVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    public Visibility DownloadVideoVisibility
    {
        get
        {
            return this.downloadVideoVisibility;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref this.downloadVideoVisibility, value);
        }
    }
```

and I will then bind the property to the visibility property of the control.
Now I want to do the came for an ApplicationBarMenuItem in windows phone 8 app, this ApplicationBarMenuItem has IsEnabled instead of visibility and it has too values also true and false instead of collapsed and visible. how do I create a property that I can bind the IsEnabled property to and control it in my view model

Comment: Well that's easier, use a boolean property

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool IsItemEnabled
{
      get {return isItemEnabled;}
      set {SetProperty(ref this.isItemEnabled,value);}
}
private bool isItemEnabled;
```

Your class should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for the binding to actually work.

Answer (score 0):

Use IValueConverter and bind in xaml like

Visibility="{Binding ConverterParameter=Visibility,Converter={StaticResource ButtonVisibility}}"